# What does the syntax '$f(a)$' mean in the context of FOL set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

Now that I have a little bit of set theory and first order logic under my belt, I have revisited some older concepts. One of these is the statement: $f(a)=b$.

Previously, I always treated this statement as purely a sort of *aliasing* statement, where I am claiming that the syntax $f(a)$ is an alternative way of referring to the variable $b$. However, I no longer think that is the *only* thing going on here.

---

Firstly, the syntax $'f(a)'$ is not intrinsically part of the language of set theory. Therefore, I assume it is a naming convention. That is to say:

$$f(a): = \text{something}$$

I played around with this a little bit and here is what I came up with:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and let $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Further, let $f \subseteq A \times B$ and $f$ be a *function* (i.e. $\forall x,y,z (\langle x,y \rangle \in f \land \langle x,z \rangle \in f \rightarrow y=z)$

In the canonical sense, we want $f(a)$ to be a reference to the second component of the ordered pair in $f$ whose first component is $a$.

Consider the set $G_{a,f}:=\{x \in B | \langle a,x \rangle \in f \}$ where $a$ and $f$ are fixed.

Because $f$ is a function and $a \in A$, $G_{a,f}$ only contains one element. Call that component $b$. So we have $G_{a,f}=\{b\}$...and we want $f(a)$ to effectively **pluck out** that element $b$.

Therefore, let $f(a):=\bigcup G_{a,f}$. Note, however, that:

$$\bigcup G_{a,f} = \bigcup \{b\}$$

Universally, you can prove the following statement: $$\forall S ( \bigcup \{S\}=S)$$

Knowing this, $\bigcup \{b\}=b$...but this is just the same thing as saying $f(a)=b$.

---

A corollary to the above comments is the following:

$\langle a,b \rangle \in f \rightarrow f(a)=b \land f(a)=b \rightarrow \langle a,b \rangle \in f$, which is a straightforward proof. Therefore:

$\langle a,b \rangle \in f \iff f(a)=b$

**Is all of this in the right ballpark?**

Thanks!

Comment: In set theory, everything is a set. A *relation* is a set of ordered pairs. A *function* is a relation (i.e. a set) satisfying the "functional condition": if $(x, y), (x,z) \in f$, then $y=z$.

Comment: Thus, being **unique** the element $b$ "associated" to the element $a$ in pair $(a,b) \in f$, we are allowed to speak of **the** value of function $f$ for input $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be: "$f(a)=b$" is simply shorthand for $$\langle a,b\rangle\in f$$ (which of course is itself a shorthand since we need to further unpack the pairing operation).

Note that this **does not** fold in the hypothesis that $f$ is a function - that's tacitly assumed when we use this notation. You could interpret "$f(a)=b$" as "$f$ is a function and $\langle a,b\rangle\in f$" if you prefer, though.

Comment: Well, I'm glad, at least, that this unnecessary train of thought led to the statement: $\langle a,b \rangle \in f \iff f(a)=b$! Cheers~